# php session is get lost after redirect to another page

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, web-development-server

i'm creating a project. but in my system the php session is get lost after redirect to another page.
the session is sometimes work. but suddenly doesn't work.
i can't catch the problem.please help me.

In index.php page code is:
i have session started on this page.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR7oP.jpg)

In login.php code is (it's dynamic loads  in index page):
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqfiA.jpg)

to redirect member_index.php page code is:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpBeW.jpg)

please help me.

Here you can see my project:
moneytradebd.com

Comment: Please don't add your code as screenshots but paste it as formatted code here.

Comment: @nkr, normally I would agree with that but I don't know if I would have spotted the error if I hadn't seen the extra spaces before `session_start()` was called

Answer (score 1):

You can't have any whitespace or carriage returns before calling `session_start()`. Starting your php code on line 3 on your index.php and member_index.php files is the problem. Start it on line 1 and it should work fine.